# Simplifying $\sum_{k=1}^n F_kF_{k+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, fibonacci-numbers

> Simplify $$\sum_{k=1}^n F_kF_{k+3}$$

I am looking for a direct proof rather than an inductive proof. I have already inductively proven the hypothesis that the sum is equivalent to

> $F_{n+2}^2-1$

but I was not able to reach this hypothesis until I was given it. I am looking for a way to reach this result without already knowing it.

Comment: Do you know the explicit formula for $F_n$ in terms of powers of the golden ratio and its conjugate?  You could use that, and the geometric series formula, for a direct proof.  But it will *not* be elegant.

Comment: I do know binet's formula, but I'd rather see a solution that does not use it because of the lack of elegance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $F_k = F_{k+2} - F_{k+1}$ and $F_{k+3} = F_{k+2} + F_{k+1}$. Thus, applying the difference of squares identity, we have that

$$F_k F_{k+3} = (F_{k+2}-F_{k+1})(F_{k+2}+F_{k+1}) = F_{k+2}^2 - F_{k+1}^2$$

So the sum is equivalent to

$$\sum_{k=1}^n F_{k+2}^2 - F_{k+1}^2$$

which is a straightforward telescoping sum! Hooray!

Comment: +1 , exactly what I would have done, nice and smooth

Comment: Assuming that "telescoping sum" is not ruled out as "induction".